# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable \\ number crunching

Tags: python-3.x

The objective of my code is to simply open a file with recorded data, read it, then print the second line without closing the file.  Below is the code that I have typed.

```
    with open("dataset.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print (line.split("\t"))[1]
```

The program ends up running, but returns the following.  The first printed index is all I want.

```
['X_Value', 'M.LM.T', 'VapPres.T', 'CCS.F1.T', 'CCS.F2.T', 'CCS.F3.T', 'AB.F4.T', 'CCS.F5.T', 'AB.M1.T', 'AB.M2.T', 'AB.M3.T', 'AB.M4.T', 'AB.M5.T', 'M.LM.R', 'CCS.F1.R', 'CCS.F2.R', 'CCS.F3.R', 'AB.F4.R', 'CCS.F5.R', 'AB.M1.R', 'AB.M2.R', 'AB.M3.R', 'AB.M4.R', 'AB.M5.R', 'Flow.SLM', 'M.LM.R 1', 'VapPres.P', 'VapPres2.P', 'Comment', '', '', '', '\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/data informatics/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print (line.split("\t"))[1]
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

When I try

```
   print (line.split("\t")[1])
```

or

```
   print (line.split("\t")[1])
```

it prints the entire column.

What should I do differently to eliminate the 'NoneType' TypeError?

Comment: `print((line.split("\t")))[1]` This is wrong syntactically in python 3.x.  please print and upload here `print (line.split("\t"))`.   what you wrote `print((line.split("\t"))[1])` should have work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @ormi_saadon  But even with this adjustment it still returns the same error. Could this be the fault of python reading a "" in the file at the end of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following in order to ignore space at the end of line:

```
with open("dataset.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print ((line.rstrip().split("\t"))[1])
```

> string.rstrip(s[, chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. If chars
>   is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed.